# File Path generate using std::ofstream

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

The following code works properly

```
    //m_outputFilePath and m_moduleName are strings

     std::string moduleVerilog;
    // call Gen function to update moduleVerilog

    std::ofstream moduleVerilogFile(m_outputFilePath + "\\" + m_moduleName + ".v");
    if (moduleVerilogFile.is_open())
    {
        moduleVerilogFile << moduleVerilog;
        moduleVerilogFile.close();
    }
```

But if I change `moduleVerilogFile` to be:

```
std::ofstream moduleVerilogFile(m_outputFilePath + "\\Verilog\\" + m_moduleName + ".v");
```

nothing is written to the file,since `moduleVerilogFile.is_open()` returns false
Should I explicitly generate `Verilog` directory?(Looks weird)

Answer (score 0):

If the `Verilog` directory doesn't exist, `std::ofstream` will not create it for you - it's purpose is reading and writing files. If the directory isn't present, it'll fail to open the file, so `is_open` will indeed be false.

Comment: The file may not present but the directory path must be valid. If the file is not present in the valid path, `std::ofstream` will create one by default and write the contents to it.